# Keyboard Shortcut for Navigation Pane - Microsoft Word for Mac version 16.44

Tags: mac, microsoft-word, keyboard-shortcuts, macbook

I am using MS Word for Mac – the most current version of the software as of Jan. 5, 2021.

Can someone please tell me what the keyboard shortcut is to access the navigation pane?

I'm sure this has been answered before; the answer just continues to elude me.

Answer (score 0):

It is not currently assigned, you can assign a custom keystroke of your own.

From the Menu Bar Tools Tab selection choose Customize Keyboard... and then for the NavPane choose View as the category and NavPane for the command, and set your custom keystrokes.

For this example I set it to Option+Control+Shift+N

[image]